# Kubernetes 401 Unauthorized, token not copied to containers

Tags: kubernetes, distributed-computing

Service Accounts are being created with secrets, however upon pod creation it looks like the token and ca cert are not copied into the pod.

Logs show:

```
[2016-12-27 16:16:29,012][WARN ][io.fabric8.elasticsearch.discovery.k8s.K8sUnicastHostsProvider] 
[James Dr. Power] Exception caught during discovery javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException : HTTP 401 Unauthorized
```

Environment variables of the pod include:

```
KUBERNETES_CA_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
```

However, the directory /var/run is empty

```
es-master-gqq7m:/var/run# pwd
/var/run 

es-master-gqq7m:/var/run# ls -la 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             6 Jun 12  2015 . 
drwxr-xr-x    9 root     root            81 Jun 12  2015 ..
```

The full definition of the replication controller is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/elasticsearch/production_cluster/es-master-rc.yaml), and includes:

```
spec:
  serviceAccount: elasticsearch
  env: 
    - name: KUBERNETES_CA_CERTIFICATE_FILE 
      value: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt

[cstelly@smcluster ~]$ kubectl get serviceaccounts
NAME            SECRETS   AGE
default         1         29d
elasticsearch   1         4d
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

### Edit

In response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363448/kubernetes-401-unauthorized-token-not-copied-to-containers/41373446#41373446), currently the apiconfig has the flag

`--admission-control=AlwaysAdmit \`

As for volume info, I ran

`kubectl describe pod <pod-name>`, and the only volume information I see is:

```
Volumes:
  storage:
    Type:   EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
```

Answer (score 0):

The service account token secret should be added as a volume when the pods are created. This is done by the ServiceAccount admission plugin.

Some questions:

1. If you inspect one of the running pods in the API, does it include a volume and volume mount referencing a service account token?
2. What admission plugins do you have configured for your API server?

Comment: Thanks - updated the original answer. Let me know if `inspect` is different than `describe pod`

Answer (score 0):

The token is itself created during admission control processing.

The setting recommended for >1.4 is

```
--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota
```

Mind the "ServiceAccount" part!

[See original doc](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/admission-controllers/#is-there-a-recommended-set-of-plug-ins-to-use)